# smptlib and email modules giving error on import and pip in python

Tags: python, email, mime, smtplib

I was working with smtplib module in python and it suddenly started giving NameError
I am getting the following error when importing smtblib or email in python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/outlook_email.py", line 25, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 48, in <module>
    import email.message
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/email/message.py", line 945, in <module>
    class MIMEPart(Message):
NameError: name 'Message' is not defined
```

I am also getting  the same error while running any pip command. For ex. pip install, pip uninstall, pip freeze all commands give the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.models import Request, Response
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import urllib3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 982, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 925, in _find_spec
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 192, in find_spec
    return spec_from_loader(fullname, self)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 431, in spec_from_loader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 222, in is_package
    return hasattr(self.__get_module(fullname), "__path__")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 121, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 118, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 87, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 72, in <module>
    import email.message
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/email/message.py", line 945, in <module>
    class MIMEPart(Message):
NameError: name 'Message' is not defined
```

I am also getting the same error while running any python script.

What can be the solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No I did not have a script named email.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled my python and upgraded to a latest 9.3 version which seemed to solve the issue.